# jQuery Mobile: Clear page when back-btn is pressed

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a hybrid application that have a lot of "sequentail" pages (Ex: Home -> Page 1 ->Page 2 -> Page 3). All this pages have set in the header data-add-back-btn= true and they load datas by AJAX. The problem is that when I push the back button I'd like to clear the content of the page because when I go in that page again it will show the previous data until the fresh data are loaded.. I've tried:

```
$('#page_one').on('pagebeforechange', function(){
    //clear
    //reload ajax
}
```

But it works yes when the page is called but also when I return back on that page from page_two. I'd like to use something like onDestroy() in Android. Does it exist ?

Thank You very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to utilize two events

1. `navigate` to determine whether a user is navigating *back* using jQM back button `data-rel="back"` or browser's back button.

   ```
   var direction = "";

   $(window).on("navigate", function (e, data) {
      direction = data.state.direction == "back" ? true : false;
   });
   ```
2. `pagebeforechange` (jQM <= 1.3) `pagecontainerbeforechange` (jQM >= 1.4). This event will return an object `.toPage` of the page you are navigating too whether or not back button is used. At his stage, you can replace contents of `toPage`.

   ```
   $(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (e, data) {
       if (direction && $.type(data.toPage) == "object") {
           /* do your magic here */
           $(".ui-content", data.toPage).append("<p>Back button was hit</p>");
           /* don't forget to reset direction var */
           direction = false;
       }
   });
   ```

> **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/6ysgx4e0/)**

Comment: Why in this example does the event fire more than once? I see it firing twice per page change. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: @Crungmungus `pagebeforechange` / `pagecontainerbefore` change fires twice, first one it returns a string, 2nd it returns an object. http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/07/13/pagecontainerbeforechange/ and http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/

Comment: @Crungmungus another solution using one event: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/detect-back-navigation/