# how to prevent window.loacation.reload() to execute before $.mobile.back() in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I was using following code to go back to previous page in using `javascript` .

**Script**

```
var posting = $.post(url, {
    im_user: user,
    im_password:password
}).done(function (data) {
   $.mobile.back();
   //window.history.back();
    window.location.reload(true);

     });
```

So if I get positive response from the $_post method then I was first closing Mobile Jquery  page using `$.mobile.back() or window.history.back()` and then reloading the page using `window.loacation.reload()`.

The problem I am facing is `window.location.reload(true)` executes before `$mobile.back()` or `window.history.back()`. How can I serialize this so that first the page goes back and then the page loads .

Note:I do not want to user delay because Its a login page delay will not look good :).

To clarify it better 
If I use following code with the delay it works fine

**UPDATE**

```
var posting = $.post(url, {
    im_user: user,
    im_password:password
}).done(function (data) {
   // alert(data);
   $.mobile.back();
   //window.history.back();
   setTimeout( function(){
    window.location.reload(true);

   },1000);
     });
```

Comment: you're reloading current view before jQM changes page and update popstate. Do you want to _reload_ whenever user go back to previous page?

Comment: ummm @Omar The situation is like this . there is an icon clicking on that it loads a Jquery Mobile Page that page has form for login and I am using Ajax/post method to send the details to server and when I get the response I have to first close the page and then reload the whole html page.

Comment: something like this should do http://stackoverflow.com/a/25210016/1771795

Comment: @Omar thanks I am going to look into it tomorrow :) .

Comment: You just need to add some conditions as this will fire whenever user hits browsers back button or any button with `data-rel=back`.